# Which logical operator will return smaller data set?

Tags: sql

Select all of the clauses below that will result in a data set smaller than a query that did not use the logical operator.

1. WHERE price = 10 AND inventory > 0;
2. WHERE price = 10 OR price = 20;
3. WHERE NOT price = 10;
4. WHERE price IS NULL;

The correct answers are #1 and #4. I know #3 is false because the original dataset might not have item which price is 10. In this case, the query with #3 clause will result in the same dataset.

But why #2 is false?

Comment: As usual: it depends (on the data  in this case). An empty table will return 0 rows for all queries

Comment: Do you have the dataset? Why not run them and look at the result?

Comment: If the table is empty all queries will return 0 rows.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is worded poorly.

2 is false because a query with `WHERE price=10 OR price=20` returns records for *both* prices, which is likely to be more records than just `WHERE price=10` alone.

But it's also very easy to interpret the "not use a logical operator" requirement as "no WHERE clause at all", which would produce more records. This interpretation is encouraged by option #4, which also effectively removes the entire WHERE clause.